# How to make browser save a specific password?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, formik

In my page I've three form fields. First two are username and password. As they enter username and password I'm rendering otp field in the same page. After they entered otp I'm logging in. Issue is browser is saving otp as password instead of actual password.

How can I make browser to save username and password entered at first and ignore otp that was entered further.

Go to this gist for code https://gist.github.com/GiriAakula/ddd6d0fd8b205567cbae3ddca22b26d5

[image: screenshot of browser saving password]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well.. you can remove the input `type="password"` for your OTP `<input />` field. Chrome will automatically ignore this field.